# ApiDescriptions returns GET functions only

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to document my APIs.  I've written in my controller the following code (VB.NET) :

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    Dim apiExplorer = config.Services.GetApiExplorer()
    Dim apiDescs = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions
    Return View(apiExplorer)
End Function
```

The problem is when I debug my code and watch what is in the `apiDescs`, I can only see GET methods only - I can't see any DELETE, PUT or even POST methods.  This is not how it should work.

Here is a sample from one of my APIs:

```
<HttpGet()>
Public Function GetX(x as integer) as String
'Code goes here
End Function

<HttpPost()>
Public sub PostX(x as integer)
'Code goes here
End Function
```

Only `GetX` is returned within `ApiDescriptions` without `PostX`.  The same goes for all POST, PUT and DELETE methods in all APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched the web and I couldn't find an answer or a similar case to mine,so since I'm not sure what exactly was going on with my project I've created a new MVC WebAPI project,checked that everything is working,then compared `webconfig` files and it seems my project didn't have those handlers in `<handlers>` section:

```
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

After adding them my project worked fine and `ApiDescriptions` now lists all methods